# How do I set a redirection in MediaWiki?

Tags: redirect, mediawiki

```
 $links['namespaces']['contacto'] = array(
        'class' => false, // false or 'selected', defines whether the tab should be highlighted
        'text' => 'Contacto', // what the tab says
        'href' => $maintitle->getFullURL(), // where it links to
        'context' => 'Contacto',
);
```

I've created a page tabs that i want to redirect to another page within my Wiki.

How do I set the redirect rule in 'href' in that code above?

Comment: Where does `$links` come from and go to? From the [SkinTemplateNavigation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SkinTemplateNavigation) hook? How should redirection look like exactly?

Comment: I want to go from the Wiki homepage to the Contact page through a 'Contact' tab